# Why is Chingachgook regarded as a romantic character?

Tags: character-analysis, james-fenimore-cooper, the-last-of-the-mohicans

In *The Last of the Mohicans: A Narrative of 1757* Chingachgook is a romantic character. He lives in harmony with nature and is loyal and brave. However, I am having trouble finding a quotation or example demonstrating this.
Could someone provide me with some examples for why is Chingachgook regarded as a romantic character?

Comment: Could you provide proof that he is a romantic character?